# Comparing multiple characters in C

Tags: c, string, char

I am making a **stone knife paper** game.(*Rock Paper Scissors*) In this assignment we have been asked to use numbers for comparison purposes. Hence the need for converting users input '**S**' or '**K**' or '**P**' to **0 , 1 ,2** repectively.I have run into trouble using the **strcmp** funtion which doesn't seem to work due to my limited understanding of pointers and characters.

```
int comp_number,user_number;
char user_guess[1], computer_guess[1];    
printf("Please enter S (for stone) or K (for Knife) or P (for Paper).\n");

    scanf("%c",&user_guess);

    comp_number = rand() % 3;

    /*
     o = stone
     1 = kinfe
     2 = paper
    */


    if(strcmp(user_guess,"S")==0 || strcmp(user_guess,"s")==0){

        user_number=0;

    }else if(strcmp(user_guess,"K")==0 || strcmp(user_guess,"k")==0){

        user_number=1;

    }else{

        user_number=2;
    }
```

Comment: It's a single character. `user_guess == 'K'` would work just fine. Why are you over-complicating? And yeah, you can use `switch/case` statement.

Comment: Try with 'S' instead of "S" and so on... `""` is for strings, `''` is for characters

Comment: @OiciTrap `strcmp` is not working with characters..

Comment: Then do what @EugeneSh. recommended or change the user input to string instead of a character, that way you will be able to use `strcmp`, but you would have to change every `'S'`, `'K'`... to `"S"`, `"K"`... etc

Comment: BTW, instead of mapping the user input to the computer generated choice, do it the other way round, that's probably easier. Hint: `char choices[] = 'SKP';` ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to do the reading and logic (that looks better) is to scan to a char then do a switch statement:

```
scanf("%c",&user_guess);

switch (user_guess) {
    case 'S':
    case 's':
        user_number=0;
        break;
    case 'K':
    case 'k':
        user_number=1;
        break;
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        user_number=2;
        break;
    default:
        // You can even do some error handling in here!
}
```

As suggested by @alk below, you can also remove some lines by using `tolower` or `toupper` to convert the case, then you only need to deal with one letter case per letter.

Comment: Wrapping `user_guess` by `toupper()`/`tolower()` removes three more lines.

Answer (score 1):

Either do

```
char user_guess[2], ... /* C-"strings" are '0'-terminated, 
                           that why you always need one more `char`. */

...

scanf("%1s", user_guess); /* Scan in ONLY 1 char! */

...

if (strcmp(user_guess, "S") == 0 || ...
```

or

```
char user_guess, ...

...

scanf("%c", &user_guess);

...

if (user_guess == 'S') || ... /* Mind the SINGLE quotes! */
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't over complicate something so simple!

Just do `if(user_guess == 'S' || user_guess == 's')`

`strcmp()` does this:

- if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.
- if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.
- if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.

So it won't work with what you want and plus it's too complex for such a simple program :)

Comment: "*So it won't work with what you want ...*" Why? It will, just do the preparation correctly.

Comment: Because it's comparing strings and returning 0 is they are same. But you want to compare only 3 characters so might as well do it via conditionals.

Comment: I understand I was just trying to suggest that the other way is over complex. But it's good that you asked this.

Answer (score 1):

No need for *user_guess* and *computer_guess* to be string.

```
int comp_number,user_number;
char user_guess, computer_guess;    

printf("Please enter S (for stone) or K (for Knife) or P (for Paper).\n");
scanf("%c",&user_guess);
comp_number = rand() % 3;

/*
 o = stone
 1 = kinfe
 2 = paper
*/

if(user_guess == 'S' || user_guess == 's'){
    user_number=0;
    printf("You chose Stone\n");
}
else if(user_guess == 'K' || user_guess == 'k'){
    user_number=1;
    printf("You chose Knife\n");
}
else{
    user_number=2;
    printf("You chose Paper\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using *ternary-condition* operator as well.

```
scanf(" %c",&user_guess);
int user_number = tolower(user_guess) == 's' ? 0
                : tolower(user_guess) == 'k' ? 1
                : tolower(user_guess) == 'p' ? 2
                : -1; // for error handling
```